# Why does printing new int[] give me an address in c++

Tags: c++, memory, int

I've learnt that using the brackets [] will dereference a pointer for you. So as new int gives an address, should this code not give you the value stored at that address as the brackets deference what is at that memory space:

```
cout << new int[3];
```

Comment: What is your source of learning? If your'e at the point of reading about `new` you may want to read on a bit. There are two forms of `new` you should know about.

Comment: "I've learnt that using the brackets [] will dereference a pointer for you" - no. That's not right. Square brackets mean different things in different contexts - C++ is a [context sensitive language/grammar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar) - the same symbols don't always do the same thing in all situations.

Comment: Im already reading a beginners book and thanks, i didnt know that the square brackets had different meanings in different contexts

Comment: For a few months, forget about "new" and pointers. If your beginner's book starts out discussing them, send it back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I've learnt that using the brackets [] will dereference a pointer for you

Like many other things in C++, use of `[]` has different meanings under different contexts.

In the the context of `new int[3]`, it does not dereference a pointer. It allocates memory for an array of 3 `int`s and returns a pointer to that memory.

The line

```
cout << new int[3];
```

is equivalent to

```
int* ptr = new int[3];
cout << ptr;
```

If you want to print one of the values, use:

```
int* ptr = new int[3];
cout << ptr[0];
```

You could use:

```
cout << (new int[3])[0];
```

but then your program will have a memory leak.

Comment: ok thanks I didnt know that it had different meanings in different contexts.

Answer (score 4):

Because `new T[C]` is not parsed as `(new T)[C]`. Instead, it is parsed as `new (T[C])`. I.e. it allocates an object of array type. It returns the address of the first element of that array, like the non-array new-expression returns the address of the new object.